# payments_detail empty in payments reports

Tags: facebook, payment

When requesting the detail payment report via https://paymentreports.facebook.com ( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/payments/developer_reports_api/ ) I always have an empty payment_detail:

SH,COMPANYID,payment_detail
CH,app_id,payment_type,product_type,payment_id,time_completed,recv_currency,recv_amount,fx_batch_id,fx_rate,settle_currency,reference_id,tax_country
SF,0

my request URL with important data left out: https://paymentreports.facebook.com/COMPANYID/report?date=2012-09-30&type=detail&access_token=ACCESSTOKEN

How can I get the payment_detail to contain data?(credits_detail has data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was at the time Facebook local currency was not yet used. The reports were for Facebook Credits and thus that part was empty.